# Proving a subset is a subspace of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To prove a subset is a subspace of a vector space we have to prove that the same operations (closed under vector addition and closed under scalar multiplication) on the Vector space apply to the subset. Fine, I get this.

But I am having trouble with the subspace tests. For example, if the question is:

> Let $W = \{(a,b,c)|a\geq b\}$ be a subset of the vector space $V$. Show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

I can do upto this:

> Let $w$ belong to $V$, and $w_1 = (a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $w_2 = (a_2,b_2,c_2)$ belong to $w$. We have to show that $w_1 + w_2$ is closed under vector addition. Therefore, $w_1 + w_2 = (a_1 + a_2,b_1 + b_2,c_1 +c_2)$.

My question is, considering what the question is asking, basically how do I solve this? How to test whether it is closed under scalar multiplication when there are two vectors involved? How do I bring in $a\geq b$ in the answer?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't closed under scalar multiplication $(1,-1,0)\in W$ yet $-1\cdot(1,-1,0) = (-1,1,0)$ is not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To show a subset is a subspace, you need to show three things:

1. Show it is closed under addition.
2. Show it is closed under scalar multiplication.
3. Show that the vector $0$ is in the subset.

To show 1, as you said, let $w_{1} = (a_{1}, b_{1}, c_{1})$ and $w_{2} = (a_{2}, b_{2}, c_{2})$.  Suppose $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ are in our subset.  Then they must satisfy $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$ and $a_{2} \geq b_{2}$.  We need to check that $w_{1} + w_{2}$ is in our subset, that is, we need to check that if

$$w_{1} + w_{2} = (a_{1} + a_{2}, b_{1} + b_{2},c_{1} + c_{2})$$

then it satisfies that the first coordinate is greater than or equal to the second coordinate.  Is $a_{1} + a_{2} \geq b_{1} + b_{2}$?  Yes, by adding the two inequalities $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$ and $a_{2} \geq b_{2}$ together.  So $w_{1} + w_{2}$ is in our subset.

For 2, we need to show that if $\alpha$ is any scalar, then if $w_{1} = (a_{1}, b_{1}, c_{1})$ is in our subset, so is $\alpha w_{1}$.  But $\alpha w_{1} = (\alpha a_{1}, \alpha b_{1}, \alpha c_{1})$.  We know since $w_{1}$ is in our subset that $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$.  We need to check that for any $\alpha$, $\alpha a_{1} \geq \alpha b_{1}$.  This inequality is definitely true if $\alpha \geq 0$, but we need it to be true for all $\alpha$, and it's not, because if $\alpha$ is negative, then multiplying the inequality $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$ on both sides by a negative number makes the inequality flip.  So we would get $\alpha a_{1} \leq \alpha b_{1}$ if $\alpha < 0$, which means the inequality doesn't hold.  Thus, if $\alpha < 0$, then $\alpha w_{1}$ is *not* in our subset because it doesn't satisfy $\alpha a_{1} \geq \alpha b_{1}$.

So our subset is *not* a subspace because it doesn't satisfy 2 (it is not closed under scalar multiplication, because any negative scalar would cause this problem).

Comment: Thanks, but when you say "Yes, by adding the two inequalities a1≥b1 and a2≥b2 together. " where do you get the inequalities from.

Comment: Also, sorry but I am having difficulty applying the same ideas to this question, Show that W = {(a,b,c)|a^2+b^2+c^2 <= 1} is not a subspace of V, where W is a subset of V. How to do take w1= (a1,b1,c1) to a1^2+b1^2+c1^2 <= 1?

Comment: @pilot We know $w_{1} = (a_{1},b_{1},c_{1})$ is in our subset, so this gives us $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$.  Also, $w_{2} = (a_{2},b_{2},c_{2})$ is in our subset, and this gives us $a_{2} \geq b_{2}$.  So we know that $a_{1} \geq b_{1}$ and $a_{2} \geq b_{2}$ because $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ are in the subset.  Adding the two inequalities gives us $a_{1} + a_{2} \geq b_{1} + b_{2}$, which means the vector $w_{1} + w_{2}$ is in our subset, since it satisfies the property that its first coordinate is greater than or equal to its second coordinate.

Comment: @pilot To show $W = \{ (a, b, c) \mid a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \leq 1 \}$ is *not* a subspace of $V$, we need to show that at least one of the three subspace conditions does not hold.  Clearly, $(0, 0, 0)$ is in $W$ since $0^{2} + 0^{2} + 0^{2} \leq 1$.  So condition 3 holds.  So either condition 1 or 2 does not hold.  I think condition 2 is easier to check, so we will check it first.  Is it true that for all scalars $\alpha$, if $u = (a, b, c)$ is in $W$, then $\alpha u$ is in $W$?  We need to check that for all $\alpha$...(continued below)

Comment: @pilot we need to check that for all scalars $\alpha$, if we know $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \leq 1$, is it true that $(\alpha a)^{2} + (\alpha b)^{2} + (\alpha c)^{2} \leq 1$ (for all $\alpha$)?  The answer is no.  By factoring out an $\alpha^{2}$ from the inequality and dividing both sides by $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}$, we see that the only $\alpha$ that satisfy this equation are those such that $\alpha^{2} \leq \dfrac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}$.  So picking an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^{2} > \dfrac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}$ means $\alpha u$ does not satisfy the condition, so it is not in $W$.

Comment: @pilot Thus, we showed that property 2 does not hold because it's not closed under scalar multiplication for every scalar.  If the scalar $\alpha$ is picked so that $\alpha^{2} > \dfrac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}$ then $(\alpha a)^{2} + (\alpha b)^{2} + (\alpha c)^{2} > 1$, so the vector $\alpha u = (\alpha a, \alpha b, \alpha c)$ is *not* in $W$ (it doesn't satisfy the condition of the subset).

Comment: @layman I think that for a real vector space there's no need to show there exists a zero vector in the subspace if we have closure under scalar multiplication since $0$ is scalar, so $0\boldsymbol{v} = O$ for any vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ in the subset. Generally speaking, though, we have to show there exists a zero vector.

Comment: @layman why is it necessary that if 1 and 2 are in our subset, then they must satisfy 1 ≥ 1 and 2 ≥ 2?

Comment: Doesn't condition #3 follow from the first two, though, since if $v$ is in the subset, then so is the scalar multiple $-v$ of $v$, and so is the sum $v+(-v)$, which is $0$ by definition of objects in the original space. Therefore $0$ is in the subset too.

Answer (score 2):

Do you suspect this is a vector space or not? If you think it *is*, you have to verify the definitions. If not, then find counterexamples.

Testing for scalar multiplication doesn't require two vectors, you examine the result of multiplying *one* vector by *one* scalar.

Hint:

> Try multiplying by the scalar $-1$, let $v = -w$ with $w \in W$. Is $v$ in $W$ also (i.e. is $-a \geq -b$?)