# Linear Algebra: Spanning Sets, Closures, Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

So I need help on three of my questions and I don't have any idea where to begin for any of these three so any help would be appreciated.

1. Determine whether the set of all solutions to the differential equation y' + y = cos(x) is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Take the set of scalars to be the set of all real numbers. (DO NOT SOLVE THE DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION)
2. Determine whether S is a subspace of vector space V, where V is the vector space of all real-valued functions defined on the interval [a,b], and S is the subset of V consisting of all functions satisfying f'(a) = f'(b).
3. Let S be the subspace of R3 consisting of all vectors of the form v =(c1 + 2c2, 5c1, 2c1 - 2c2). Determine a set of vectors that spans S.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's say $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ are solutions, i.e. 
   $y_i(x)'=\cos(x)-y(x)$, for $i=1,2$. Then what can you tell me about $y_1(x)+y_2(x)?$ What about $cy_i(x)$ for some scalar c? Hint, use the only thing you know about the two functions and differentiate. This will show closure under addition and scalar multiplication.
2. Well if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $g(a)=g(b)$, then what does $(g+f)(a)=$?
3. What can you say about the vectors $(1,5,2)$ and $(2,0,-2)$? Can you make vectors of that form, with constants $c_1,c_2$ with these vectors?

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose $y(x)$ and $h(x)$ are solutions to $y'+y=\cos x$ (viz.$y'(x) = -y(x) + \cos(x)$ and $h'(x) = -h(x) +\cos x$). The question is asking you whether or not $ay(x) + bh(x)$ is also a solution for any constant scalars $a,b$. Hint: take the derivative of  $g(x) = ay(x) + bh(x)$.
2. This question is asking you (i) whether or not $S$ is a vector space, and (ii) whether or not $f\in S\Rightarrow f\in V$. If the answer to (i) and (ii) is yes then $S$ is a subspace of $V$, if not, then it isn't.  [Proving a subset is a subspace of a Vector Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871145/proving-a-subset-is-a-subspace-of-a-vector-space) has a guide to proving (i) and proving (ii) is trivial.
3. Anything that spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ also spans $S$ since $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Think of any set of vectors which spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hint: any basis of a space must also span that space.